# Java How to configure JAVA_OPTS environment variable to do not display in log

Tags: tomcat, logging

I have taken the password as an Environment variable and configured it in my tomcat
so, it's showing in log while deploy my code on to  server, how do i configure in tomcat to do not show my password in log?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's showing in log"? Show an example please

Comment: Yes it's showing in log.......I configured like  export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djasypt.encryptor.password=mypassword"     in my setenv.sh file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing JAVA\_OPTS environment variable in log How do i configure it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52295636/showing-java-opts-environment-variable-in-log-how-do-i-configure-it)

Comment: Yes. It's duplicate of showing-java-opts-environment-variable-in-log-how-do-i-configure-it?