# Showing JAVA_OPTS environment variable in log How do i configure it?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I have configured my ENV variable in my tomcat like `export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dpassword=password"`. It's showing in the log. How do I configure it to not show in the tomcat log.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the `VersionLoggerListener` by commenting this line in `conf/server.xml` :

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
```

It will hide not only the password but also the other variables. Please note that startup variables *should* be in `CATALINA_OPTS`, not `JAVA_OPTS`.

Example for setenv.sh :

```
SAC_DISPLAY_COPYRIGHT=0
CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx2g -Djasypt.encryptor.password=mypassword"
```

Comment: It's not working, still showing in log, I commented the VersionLoggerListener and changed the startup variables to CATALINA_OPTS.

Comment: I tested on several versions, and disabling this Listener by commenting this line inhibits the variables output at the startup. I don't see any `org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log` lines anymore in catalina.out. Post your setenv.sh + server.xml if you don't see any mistake.

Comment: Here i am posting my file code here, please check   setenv.sh file -------   export SAC_DISPLAY_COPYRIGHT=0
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djasypt.encryptor.password=mypassword"    then   in  my server.xml is   <!-- <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" /> -->
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->

Comment: I updated my answer with your last comments. I tried, this is working. What Tomcat version are you using ?

Comment: Do you see lines containing "org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log" ? If no this means that commenting the Listener was efficient. It is no more Tomcat itself that is logging, but your application (a servlet configured with load-on-startup for example). I can't help more, check your application code.